# How to export CRM 2011 SSRS reports as SQL query reports, instead of fetchXML reports?

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, reporting-services, crm

When I download report from CRM 2011 all queries are exported as fetch XML. I know this is for support of Online version of CRM. But our deployment is on-premises, and there is no need of messy fetch xml queries. Is there a way to download reports so, that queries are in SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not just for Online, but for any Internet Facing Deployment (IFD) as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you download reports from CRM 2011, all queries are not necessarily exported as fetchXML -- only if those queries were originally written in fetch will they be exported as fetch.

For example, download the rdl for the Account Overview built in report -- it contains:

```
set @sql = '
SELECT top 10 CAST(accountid as nvarchar(100)) as AccountID, 
    name
FROM (' + @CRM_FilteredAccount + ') as fa'

exec(@sql)
```

You can convert fetchXML to SQL with [linqpad's Linq2CRM extention](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/crmlinqpad) or without any 3rd party tools just set a SQL trace and execute your fetch to capture the SQL statement.

EDIT: Also it has been mentioned that FetchXML reports can perform better in CRM because of security concerns. So if messy is your only concern, perhaps potential performance trumps that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But a second questions arises. How to specify CRM to create report as SQL? Cause I don't want to create report from scratch, but want to have basic query, parameters (which will be used by CRM system for filtering and etc.). Is the only way to create it then convert fetchXML to SQL? OR May be there a setting for specifying report type?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the report wizard to generate your reports then? In that case, you are stuck with fetchXML, but could convert it to SQL by the method I mention above. If oyu want to write SQL reports from scratch, you can generate them with the BIDS extension. See here for a discussion of the differences between the report wizard and bids: http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.ca/2011/07/sql-vs-fetchxml-reports-in-crm-2011.html